# How can i get simple yyyy-MM-dd out of this date?

Tags: java, android

I have String with date format dd.MM.yyyy, and I want to upload it to my MS SQL server, but the required format is yyyy-MM-dd. I tried this but it doesn't work like I want to.

```
    String expDate = mDatePickerBtn.getText().toString();
    Date date = null;

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
    try {
        date = format.parse(expDate);
        expDate = date.getYear() + "-" + date.getMonth() + "-" + date.getDay();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

For example if I pass 31.12.2032 to the expDate, the date variable will cointain "Fri Dec 31 00:00:00: GMT+01:00 2032", and the expDate will contain "132-11-5" and I don't even know why.
I would use DateTimeFormatter but my minimal API level is 24.

My question is: where did I make mistake or how else can I get correct format out of this?

Comment: is date a java.util.Date?

Comment: FYI those methods have been deprecated since java 1.1. (that is since 1997).

Comment: use all caps in your SimpleDateFormat, "DD.MM.YYYY" and in Java, ```getDate()``` is the correct getter if you want the correct day of the month

Comment: Have a look at [API desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) and see that you have to compile your project with Gradle 4 and get `java.time` (or a subset of it) to work below API level 26.

Comment: as @FedericoklezCulloca already mentioned, these APIs have been deprecated since Java 1.1. Try using ```Calendar``` or ```LocalDateTime``` for dates.

Comment: @Kapil I think neither `Calendar` (outdated as well), nor `LocalDateTime` (no time to be parsed) are best fit for a date `String` like the example given here. I would prefer just a `LocalDate`...

Comment: @deHaar Agree, I meant to say the new APIs. ```LocalDateTime``` and ```LocalDate``` would be the new ones. ```Calendar``` on the other hand is outdated, but still useful and not deprecated.

Comment: @Kapil OK, maybe `Calendar` is still useful sometimes, that's why it's called **outdated** but not **deprecated**. Should be avoided anyway...

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: @Kapil `SimpleDateFormat` is a notorious troublemaker of a class, `DD.MM.YYYY` is wrong and `getDate()` has been deprecated for over 23 years because it works unreliably across time zones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way

```
  String expDate = mDatePickerBtn.getText().toString();
    Date date = null;

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
    try {
        date = format.parse(expDate);
        
        SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
        format1.format(date);
        
        expDate =  format1.format(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Go [compile your app with Android Gradle Plugin 4.0.0+ and use `java.time`](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) then like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // get / provide the String to be parsed
    String expDate = "31.12.2032";
    // provide a pattern that parses such a date
    String pattern = "dd.MM.uuuu";
    // create a DateTimeFormatter with this pattern
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern); 
    // parse the String with the DateTimeFormatter
    LocalDate expLocalDate = LocalDate.parse(expDate, dtf);
    // print the default format of a LocalDate
    System.out.println(expLocalDate);
    // print the LocalDate using the pattern created for parsing
    System.out.println(expLocalDate.format(dtf));
    // create a totally different DateTimeFormatter inline and format the date differently
    System.out.println(expLocalDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE, dd 'of' MMMM uuuu",
                                                                        Locale.ENGLISH)));
}
```

The output would be this:

```
2032-12-31
31.12.2032
Fri, 31 of December 2032
```